# How do you disable ibus in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, ibus

How do you disable ibus in 20.04?

The ~/.xinputrc "run_im none" override created by im-config and gnome-language-selector is no longer enough, ibus is still started and is active. I am aware of being able to disable ibus shortcuts via ibus-setup, but I would prefer disabling it (without uninstalling it).

Comment: It's not enough since GNOME itself launches and configures IBus. Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: That does not explain anything; gnome-shell is not a system service, its running in the context of the account, so why would it ignore the setting that is meant to disable ibus for the account?

Comment: Please feel free to study the code if you don't believe me. `im-config` does not explicitly disable anything; by setting "none" you just tell it to back off. But GNOME does not back off...

Comment: I didn't say I didn't believe you, I can see that gnome-shell is starting ibus. The question is why, when gnome-language-selector has it disabled? One way or another there's a bug here. If gnome-shell now has a hardcoded dependency on ibus for some reason, then gnome-language-selector should not have a pretend to disable ibus ui.

Comment: I see your point. But `im-config` (to which `gnome-language-selector` offers a simple UI) is there to let users choose the input method framework (IBus is just one of those) and designed to work on any desktop environment. GNOME is an exception due to its special integration of IBus. Why don't you let us know what it is you want to achieve? You said something about shortcuts...

Comment: It has been found somewhere around the end of https://wiki.debian.org/InputMethodBuster , I guess.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/719792/515980) worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

I can see why you would want to get rid of iBus, that takes over the keyboard, and whose functionalities (mostly insert emojis) you may not need / use, so

`ibus exit`

Like for instance in my i3 config:

`exec --no-startup-id ibus exit`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg-divert --package im-config --rename /usr/bin/ibus-daemon
```

Comment: It would be better if you could expand on your answer...